# MongoDB '$or' and regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, or-operator

I know there are tons of subjects about "MongoDB $or PHP", but I'm unable to understand this;

Assuming I've a collection `Compagnies`:

```
$Mongo->Compagnies->insert({"Name":"BoldLine", "Service":"Billing", "Description":"Hello World"});
$Mongo->Compagnies->insert({"Name":"Behobe", "Service":"Development", "Description":"Here we are cool"});
```

My need is to execute an 'or' query on this collection, using regex. So I did:

```
use \MongoRegex as MR;

$regex = new MR ("/B/i");    //Where field contains the letter 'B'

$Mongo->Compagnies->find(
    array(
        '$or'   =>  array(
            array(
                "Name"          =>  $regex,
                "Service"       =>  $regex,
                "Description"   =>  $regex
                )
            )
        )
);
```

But there is 0 result. Why? The result shouldn't be the 2 lines? 
Now if I do :

```
$Mongo->Compagnies->find(
    array(
        '$or'   =>  array(
            array(
                "Name"          =>  $regex,
                "Service"       =>  $regex
                )
            )
        )
);
```

The result will be only the first line. I don't understand why the second line doesn't match the query, because there is also 'B' in the Name. It seems the '$or' operator acts like '$and'.

Did I miss something? How can I select all entities containing the letter 'B' in one of the 3 fields, even if one or more other field doesn't not contain this letter?

Thank you :)

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php#116000, this does not look like a regex issue, but how you use it with `$or`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Same result :(
Edit: Yes, I guess it's a missuse of the or operator, I'm able to use the regex without any issues with no or-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each or condition should be in different array.
Try this:

```
$Mongo->Compagnies->find(
array(
    '$or'   =>  array(
        array(
            "Name"             =>  $regex,
        ),
         array(
            "Service"          =>  $regex,
        ),
         array(
            "Description"      =>  $regex,
        ),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Rectification, you are absolutely right, that was my syntax. Thank you!

Comment: This was the solution :)